# How to create a group, add users to the group, and have that user access all folders in files in that directory?

Tags: server, permissions, users

I want to basically create a group called Staff. I want staff to be able to access the folder `/home/Clients` and all of the subdirectories and files inside the `Clients` folder.

How would I go about creating the group, and how would I create the users to be able to download and access all these files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

Do the following:

1. Add group:

   ```
   sudo addgroup staff
   ```
2. Add user to group:

   ```
   sudo adduser mike staff
   ```
3. Give group access to folder:

   ```
   sudo chgrp -R staff /home/Clients
   ```
4. Set permissions on folder:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 775 /home/Clients
   ```
5. Make all folders subsequently created inside `/home/Clients` to be owned by `group` `staff`:

   ```
   sudo setfacl -dR -m g:staff:rwx /home/Clients
   ```

Comment: When i do #5 it says setfacl: Option -m: Invalid Argument near character 1

Comment: Sorry updated the answer @AustinPrado

Comment: Just realized for step 2 the command does not work.  adduser -g name staff
I ran this command but  realized it says adduser: user 'name' already exists

Comment: That option `-g` should not be there, please see `man adduser`!

Comment: This should have more upvotes!  Good explanation(s), recursive `chmod`.  I wish I could upvote you 10 times, but please settle for this heartfelt "thanks!" since I can't  :-)

Comment: Oh my, @GeorgeUdosen!  I didn't even see the "make future folders owned by group x" !  A rare gem of an underrated, new answer!

Comment: [More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-do-i-change-permissions-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in) on chmod permissions

Answer (score 1):

I named group of downloaders "dlers" in example. Also change user "joe" enter that group.

```
sudo groupadd dlers
sudo chgrp dlers /home/Clients
sudo adduser joe dlers 
sudo chmod 770 /home/Clients # users not in group dlers cannot vi
```